# Why does jQuery alls Alert() more times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

I currently have a quite big issue here, which I've been trying to figure out since yesterday, but I really don't know what could be the problem here.

So I basically made a jQuery Ajax call in my code, something like this:

```
var ajaxCall = function(id, token)
{
    var datap = { "id": id, "token": token };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: datap,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            // loading image
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
           setting(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

As for the success function you can see the `setting` function, which looks like this:

```
var setting = function(data)
{
    $('#testDiv').html(data.country);
}
```

Basically, this ajax call is made, once someone clicks on an item like:

```
$('#popup').on("click", function(){
    ajaxCall();
});
```

So when someone clicks in the popup button, they will have a popup window open with the loaded Ajax content.

This is actually working flawlessly. My only problem happens, if I want to make another event within the Popup window (like: on click).

```
var load = function()
{
    $('#testDiv #button').on("click", function(){
        alert(1);
    }
}
```

So if I place it in the above Ajax call function, it looks like the following:

```
$('#popup').on("click", function(){
    ajaxCall();
    load();
});
```

### **Problem:**

When I click on the opoup button, to load the popup window, it loads the Ajax content. When I try to click on `#button` within the popup window at the first time, after loading the page, it gives me the alert box with 1.

However! If I just close the opoup window and click on it again, to load the popup, than click on the `#button` again, now I got the `alert(1)` **2 times**! If I do the above again, I got it **3 times**, **4 times**, and so on.

So basically I've found out, that if I use the `on Click` function (within the popup window, after ajax has loaded), the contents within the `on Click` function got called more times, if I load the popup window more times (without refreshing the page - after refresh, everything strats from the beginning).

So the first popup load and click is normal, but the others seems to get called more times. I have also checked that the Ajax call is called multiple times, but it's NOT. I have placed an increment number inside each part of the code and I only got it incremented multiple times when the `#button` was clicked.

I know that this is quite hard to understand, but I would really need someone's help here, as I'm completely lost. Any solutions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should try `$(document).on("click", '#testDiv #button',function(){alert(1);}` You should learn [event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: do not bind click event in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event whenever load is called, to fire it once, you should bind it once. Either unbind it every time you call load before binding it or use on for event delegation. If you have to bind event with ids then you should directly bind as id are supposed to be using do not use descendant selector.

```
var load = function()
{
    $('#testDiv #button').off("click");
    $('#testDiv #button').on("click", function(){
        alert(1);
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to use event delegation for dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on("click", '#testDiv #button',function(){
   alert(1);
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

**Edit** based on comments

As both elements are present in dom and not loaded dynamically you simply need click event. As ids are supposed to be unique do not use parent child selector

```
$('#testDiv').on("click", function(){ 
    alert(1); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The weird thing is, that I have tried your first solution, and it has worked great. However when I try your second solution, it works the exact same was as before. So why could this happen?

Comment: Are these two #testDiv #button different elements you want to bind event or you want to bind event on #button within #testDiv?

Comment: I would like to make #button to be clickable, which is whithin #testDiv (the popup window).

Comment: Are these both added dynamically?

Comment: $('#testDiv #button').on("click", function(){
   alert(1);
});

Comment: This is what I did as you can read above:
var load = function()
{
    $('#testDiv #button').on("click", function(){
        alert(1);
    }
}

Comment: Please read the Original post. I created the exact same event handler as you can see in the original post. This is why I've created this question. The problem is that it keeps assigning the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this:

Bind your click event outside of that function and put it in doc ready:

```
$('#testDiv #button').on("click", function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

and do this in the `#popup` click event:

```
$('#popup').on("click", function(){
   ajaxCall();
   $('#testDiv #button').trigger('click');
});
```